# How to change the display of @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I made a DataBase Fisrt MVC project and I'm having some issues with this.
This is the Index of one of my Views:
And for example, I would like

> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)

to be displayed as "User" instead of "name".

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
@model IEnumerable<dispensario.pacientes>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cedula)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.carnet)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tipo_paciente)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.estado)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cedula)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.carnet)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tipo_paciente)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.estado)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.idPaciente }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.idPaciente }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.idPaciente })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to be displayed as "User" instead of "name"" ?

Comment: Do you have a property named as "User" inside your "pacientes" class ?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add DisplayName attribute to your viewmodel.

```
[DisplayName("User")]
public string name { get; set; }
```

In your view: 
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)

Or you can just write "User" to view instead of html helper.

i.e. in your view:

```
<th>User</th>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'd never imagined it would be as easy as writing "User" on the view as <th>User</th>

Answer (score 3):

Add DisplayName Attribute to your property to change the display name in your model

```
[DisplayName("User")]
public string name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same "problem" and to properly use the Data Annotation *[DisplayName("User")]* in Visual Studio Code I had to add the *using System.ComponentModel;* to my model file. Without this using I could not compile successfully. Hope this tip could help someone